# Объясните пожалуйста как работает этот код

Tags: javascript, область-видимости, замыкания

```
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();
```

Comment: **Почитайте справку:** [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку здесь до меня уже были довольно подробные объяснения в 2 ответах, то я напишу немного иначе:  ***очень облегчает понимание кода, если его записывать в развёрнутом виде***.

Ваша функция и её вызов вида `delay(function(){console.log('test')}, 50);` будут полностью соответствовать нижеследующему развёрнутому виду:

```js
var delay = function()
{
    /*  переменная timer связана с областью видимости
        переменных. В данном случае она не засоряет
        глобальную область видимости, но при этом видима
        для функции funcTimeout.
        Читайте подробней про «Замыкания и область видимости» тут:
        https://learn.javascript.ru/functions-closures
        Про область видимости переменных тут:
        https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx
    */
    var timer = 0;

    function funcTimeout(callback, ms)
    {
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    }

    //возвращает ссылку на функцию (но на этом месте
    //вместо неё можно писать саму функцию без имени)
    return funcTimeout
}

//Срока кода ниже делает следующее:
//сначала получает ссылку на функцию, а затем
//вызывает функцию с передачей входных значений. 
delay()(function(){console.log('test')}, 50);
```

Немного проще последнюю строчку кода можно записать так:

```
//получаем ссылку на функцию:
var delayInnerFunction = delay();
//затем вызываем функцию
delayInnerFunction(function(){console.log('test')}, 50);
```

Надеюсь теперь вы сможете понять эту функцию. А записывают их так кратко для того, чтобы передавать меньше кода, ибо передача кода с сервера клиенту – это дополнительные расходы и на клиенте и на сервере.

Comment: Сервер не сгорит, если передаст имеванную функцию)) Читабельность кода имеет не меньшее значение чем его производительность.

Answer (score 0):

Это пример [замыкания](https://learn.javascript.ru/functions-closures). Очень важная часть языка javascript. Приведенный вами пример делает следующие:

1. Присваивает переменной `delay` анонимную функцию (объявленную на строке 3), которая имеет доступ к локальной области видимости анонимной функции, объявленной на строке 1, а именно к переменной `timer`. То что анонимная функция, объявленная на строке 1, "окружена скобочками" делает её вызываемой на месте.
2. В при вызове функции `delay` (по сути анонимной функции объявленной на строке 3) отменяется ранее запущенный [`timer`](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval) и запускается новый (ссылка на него сохраняется в локальной области видимости анонимной функции, объявленной на строке 1 (в переменной `timer`) и доступ к ней у нас есть только через вызов анонимной функции, сохраненной в переменной ’delay’).

Теперь, вызывая функцию, хранящийся в переменной `delay`, мы должны передать ей функцию обратного вызова и время в миллисекундах, когда эта функция (обратного вызова) должна будет вызвана.

Answer (score 0):

Переменной `delay` присваивается результат выполнения немедленно вызываемой функции -а именно функция с таймером. 
внутри  этой функции `timer` -применяется для  сохранения `id` таймера, если вызвать вызвать ее несколько раз то если предыдущий раз эта функция еще не выполнилась (таймер не успел сработать) то таймер сбрасывается и начинается отсчет по новой. Могу непонятно пояснить. прилагаю пример применения функции.

```js
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

delay(function(){console.log('test1')},100);
delay(function(){console.log('test2')},100);
delay(function(){console.log('test3')},100);
delay(function(){console.log('test4')},100);
```

выполнится только последний вызов, так как предыдущие таймеры сбросятся.